# React Navigation Custom Tab Typescript Params

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am developing projects with Typescript language with React Native library. While creating a Custom Tab Bar, parameters include **state, descriptors, and navigation**. What should I specify as a type with this?

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;

  if (focusedOptions.tabBarVisible === false) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;
........
```

Answer (score 4):

- Top Tab Navigator = "MaterialTopTabBarProps"
- Bottom Tab Bar = "BottomTabBarProps"

```
import { BottomTabBarProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';  

import { MaterialTopTabBarProps } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
```

Comment: this should be in the docs :/

Answer (score 1):

```
interface TabBarProps {
  state: TabNavigationState<ParamListBase>;
  descriptors: BottomTabDescriptorMap;
  navigation: NavigationHelpers<ParamListBase, BottomTabNavigationEventMap>;
}

const MyTabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation }: TabBarProps) => {
...
```

Comment: This is the same as the top answer just manually imported each type.